# Facebook batch friend list editor

Tags: facebook, friend-list

Is there an application (preferrably a web app, but a desktop app would be useful as well) for better Facebook friend list management?

I tend to use my Facebook friend lists like tags, where I will use contextual lists to manage my friends, e.g. Texas, Canada—for regional tagging—, as well as football, photography for interest tagging.

Is there a way to manage these lists effectively, and in a batch way?

Like "search for all people from California, and put them in a list CA"?
Or "delete all friends in list UNKNOWN"

Or: add everyone from this list to that list…

---

Facebook also introduced some new features: you can now search your friends by their interests or location, which makes it easier to create these lists. However: no batch edit mode yet.

Answer (score 5):

Just found a webapp that may be a start http://dtinth.github.io/friendlist/
it's a bit better as an interface to manage friend lists, but nowhere as powerful as what I would love to have :(

EDIT: Link updated as it was returning a 404. It is worth noting that this development on this web app has been stopped. However, you can find the source code on Github https://github.com/dtinth/friendlist

Comment: Didn't work for me on firefox (I just see the parragraph on top), but worked fine on midori, odd.

Comment: This is great tool, also there's a newer version allow to edit `list`. Though we cannot quickly/batch delete all friends in a list

Comment: the link is not working anymore...... any idea where is the new URL ?

Comment: @user41932 I have updated the link (Although it worth noting that development has been stopped)

Comment: Updated link not working for me - freezes on 'Initializing: Getting Facebook Session'