# How to delete all friends in a facebook list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friends

There's a great tool to manipulate friends into list as raised [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/14565/3520).

Though we cannot quickly/batch delete all friends in a list.

If you know how to do this, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while ago, I had to delete friends in a list I had previously maintained. For that purpose, I used this userscript. http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/43404

The script works out of the box in Google Chrome and requires you to install Greasemonkey extension in Firefox. I reckon it should work fine in other web browsers as well.